# ssh port forwarding: cannot tunnel to a third server

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, remote-access, ssh-tunnel, remote-connection

I want to connect to a server (C; `ip=1.0.0.3`) from my desktop (A;`ip=1.0.0.1`) via another server (B; `1.0.0.2`). I must need port forwarding to run ipython notebook remotely on server C from my desktop and the direct access is not available. This should be straight forward:

```
ssh -NfL localhost:2023:1.0.0.3:2021 user@1.0.0.2
```

Note that I am already running the `jupyter notebook` using port `2021` on `1.0.0.3`.
But this is not working.
Surprisingly, if I do it in two steps things work perfectly:

1. On A: `ssh -L localhost:2023:localhost:2022 user@1.0.0.2`
2. Then on B: `ssh -L localhost:2022:localhost:2021 1.0.0.3`

Can anyone help me to do everything in one command, please? I am utterly confused as the single code mentioned above used to work on another network system (not these servers).

Comment: The two-step method ultimately reaches the listening program on C by connecting from C to C. Your straightforward command reaches the listening program by connecting from B to C. Therefore (1) make sure the program listens on the right network interface (not only on `localhost`) and (2) make sure the firewall on C allows connections incoming from the outside to this port. I'm not posting this as an answer because it turned out you want the connection to C to be secured by SSH. If this is your requirement then please [edit] the question and place it there, not only in a comment under an answer.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Kamil, I do not really get your comment/suggestion. I could understand much better if you please post some command that explains what I should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the administrator of server B has set `PermitOpen localhost:*` in its `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file? That would restrict the remote end of incoming `ssh -L` port forwardings to localhost only.

Note that when you are using `ssh -NfL localhost:2023:1.0.0.3:2021 user@1.0.0.2`, only the first hop of the forwarded connection (from A to B) is encrypted by SSH: the connection from B to port 2021 of C will be plain TCP, not protected by SSH's encryption.

With the two-step method, both hops of the forwarded connection will be within encrypted SSH tunnels. If there is a policy requirement to avoid unencrypted connections, the administrator of server B could have added the above-mentioned `sshd_config` setting to enforce compliance.

If your version of `ssh` is recent enough to support the `ProxyJump` configuration option, you might be able to set up the equivalent (as far as port forwardings are considered) of the two-step connection with a single command:

```
ssh -J user@1.0.0.2 -NfL localhost:2023:localhost:2021 user@1.0.0.3
```

This can be tricky to understand, but it works out like this:

```
ssh ... user@1.0.0.3   # this defines what we want to think as the "main" SSH 
                       # connection: the remote end of the port forwarding 
                       # tunnel(s) will be at 1.0.0.3 (C)

-J user@1.0.0.2        # ... but use user@1.0.0.2 as an intermediate
                       # step for everything, including...

-NfL localhost:2023:localhost:2021 
                       # ... the port forwarding tunnel from
                       # the local (A) localhost:2023 to the
                       # ultimate remote's (C) localhost:2021
```

The `ssh -J`/`ProxyJump` has one added advantage compared to the two-step method: you don't have to provide any SSH private keys to host B to automate the B -> C step, as all the authentication credentials will be provided directly from host A.

Comment: Thanks. Can I change the ssh options to make both connections secured?

Comment: "the equivalent of the two-step connection" – Not quite. `-J` is not equivalent to the two-step connection described in the question. In the question the SSH connection that reaches C starts at B and uses credentials (like private keys) and `ssh_config` available on B. With `-J` the connection to C starts at A. It gets tunneled via B, but it uses credentials and `ssh_config` available on A; on B SSH client is not used, only SSH server.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Good point: I was thinking in terms of port forwardings and their protection within SSH tunnels, not about authentication credential sources.

Comment: wow, `ssh -J user@1.0.0.2 -NfL localhost:2023:localhost:2021 user@1.0.0.3` works perfectly, thank you so much.
One issue: I have to provide my ultra long password twice, this is quite annoying. Can we do something about it?

Comment: You could use SSH keys for authentication, if the server administrators have not blocked it. Depending on where you'll want to be on the security vs. convenience axis, you could use a) a SSH key stored on a Yubikey or similar physical token, b) a regular SSH key with a passphrase, c) a SSH key stored on a SSH agent (requiring you to enter the passphrase only once), or d) a passphraseless key, with possibly added options in the remote `authorized_keys` file to lock it down to allow that key for the execution of a specific task only...

Comment: As I technically got the answer to my question, I am marking your answer as accepted. But the need of putting super long password twice makes it very annoying. So I am seeking help from you to make the solution a bit more convenient.
1. The sys admin of server B and C has made 'PubkeyAuthentication no' in `ssh_config` which is readonly and I suppose I cannot edit it.  So I cannot use the 'authorized_keys' ?

Comment: 2. In the two step process mentioned above: from server B to C I can directly `ssh` without providing any user: for example `ssh 1.0.0.3` would work on server B. Actually server C is a node on the server B which is cluster of a high computing facility. My question is in the `ProxyJump` solution why do we need `user@1.0.0.3`? If we could avoid using `user` we could circumvent requiring the password twice!

Comment: 3. If somehow in the `ProxyJump` method I must put the password twice, is it possible to sum up the two step process into one function and put this in `bashrc`? For example using sleeps?

Comment: Note that my HPC requires 2fA login.